# What does `func.call(null, ..)` do?

Tags: javascript

```
var f1 = function(input) {
    var result = 1;
    return result;
}

var get_encrypted = function(func) {
    var str = 'zzoon';

    return function() {
        return func.call(null, str);
    }
}

var encrypted_value = get_encrypted(f1)();
```

I can't understand this code.
what does `func.call(null,str);` mean?
please explain this code , on the whole.

Comment: It means, call the function `fun` i.e. `f1` and pass it the param `str`. Can simply written as `func(str);`

Comment: See [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). Whenever there is a question about a method, look first at the documentation.

Comment: The other parts of the question require "learning closures". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1 and [Eloquent JavaScript: Higher-order Functions](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html) as a start.

Comment: Note to close voters: You may find this question to be not useful, since the OP did not do any research. That's a fine reason to downvote. But I'm confused by voting to close. This question is certainly neither "too broad", nor certainly a "request for outside resource". Please vote to close only when a question is really off-topic, not just because you don't like it. That's what down votes are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, here's a reference to [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Basically, the first parameter in `call()` is the `this` object you desire to use in the called function.
The called function in this case is `f1`, by the code: `get_encrypted(f1)`.

So `get_encrypted` gets the function `f1` as a parameter, and then calls `f1`, with `this` as `null` (when `null` is passed as first parameter). Now `f1` can use `this` in its code, but in this case it would not be worthwhile as `this` would be `null`. `f1` also get `'zzoon'` as second parameter for `input`, but it ignores `input`.

When `get_encrypted` gets called, by the code `get_encrypted(f1)();`, it returns the result (of a function that returns the result) of the function `f1`, where `f1` used or might have used `null` as `this`. This result is `1`.